# sql limit left side of left join

Tags: sql, left-join, limit

I've got a database on which I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
select blog.name, blog.createDate,
  post.author, post.content,
  comments.author, comments.createDate
from blogs
left join post on post.blogId = blog.id
left join comments on comments.postId = post.id
limit 0,10;
```

The problem is that I want to query all blogs with posts with comments for the first 10 blogs. Now I'm querying the first 10 comments instead of the first 10 blogs. I want the first 10 blogs with all posts containing all comments. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the number of blogs you are querying

```
Select b.Name, b.CreateDate, post.author, post.content,
       comments.author, comments.createDate
From Comments c
Join Post p on c.PostId = p.Id
Join (Select Id, Name, CreateDate From Blogs limit 0, 10) b on p.BlogId = b.Id
```

We join the blogs as a subquery that limits to the first 10 (you would add an `Order By` section there if you want to define how you want to retrieve that first 10), and then join to the other tables.